# Debugging web project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My company has its own framework which gives common look,feel and sso capabilities. It has its own installation which basically creates an ear and datasource, queues. Then wars of indiviudal products are added manually inside that ear along with thirdparty jar and application library jars.

My question is how can I debug individual war which I build using eclipse. Since this war refer to other moudules in complete ear I can't deploy single war to weblogic and since I dont have source code for ear I can't set up ear project in eclipse.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the WebLogic startup script to allow for remote debugging, and then start a remote debugging session from Eclipse.

Here's [a post explaining the process entirely](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html).